# Long Running request stops all the ASP.Net site until complete

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have an asp.net site with long running report when I try to render this report all the site stops and wait till report rendered.

I'm the only user for the site.

I tried to open the site from different browser to start different session with no result.

I tried to open different pages that not connected to any database with no result.

This site developed with Asp.Net 4.5 and published with IIS 7.5.

I thought that ASP.Net Run every request in isolated thread , so why this happen